# Does Chrome 12 really support CSS 3D transforms? Including on Linux?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, 3d, webkit, css-transforms

I'm using Chrome 12 in a Linux 64bit box, but I can't get any of the samples bellow to work:

- http://www.satine.org/research/webkit/snowleopard/snowstack.html
- http://www.marcofolio.net/css/3d_animation_using_pure_css3.html
- http://kevchapman.co.uk/css/webkit-css-perspective-demo/

They all use `-webkit-perspective`, but the final results differ a lot from the results got in Safari (Windows XP). So, after all, does Chrome support CSS 3D transforms? Or the support is still limited?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually ALL implementations of CSS3 and HTML5 are somewhat experimental, because the very specification is always in the "bleeding edge" of experimentalism.

Comment: I think the problem is the Graphic Card not the OS, as mentionned by Olegbl4. I faced a similar problem. Unfortunately, I have no satisfying answer yet. Here is the question, in case it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902720/detect-if-computer-can-support-3d-transforms-properly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to the [Chromium web SCM interface](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/browser/resources/gpu_blacklist.json?revision=75130&view=markup&pathrev=75130) and check that your GPU isn't blacklisted.

Also, go to chrome://gpu/ and check that Chrome reports 3D CSS as enabled.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that 3d support in webkit browsers depends on your videocard. That's why you cannot see that examples, but your browser engine still supports 3d transforms. To resolve this problem you can use Modernizr, which detects browser+videocard 3dtranforms support.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Chrome on a Windows 7 machine right now, and all the demos seemed to behave exactly as they should have. Have you tried Chrome on your XP machine?

Comment: Yes, I have. But I tested in VirtualBox, since I don't have access right now to a phisical machine with XP. Safari works as expected, though. I saw something about Chrome disabling -webkit-perspective in old graphic cards, but my card isn't old, and my drivers are up to date.

Comment: I'll be back in a minute with test results from an XP machine.

Comment: XP machine is not rendering the demos in 3D, but it's an old laptop, so the problem could be Chrome handling it differently as you mentioned. I have two more Windows 7 machine at home I'll test with tonight, but I expect the results will be the same.

Comment: Thans, @Mannimarco! As of the Linux side, maybe it doesn't support 3D transforms yet (Safari added support for OS X first, then for Windows). I'll try to confirm this.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, but it worked on both systems. So, as you said, it's likely the operating system, not the browser.