# css 3d not working on linux chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome, css

Hey i was wondering if anyone else has had problems with css 3d running on chrome on linux (specifically fedora 17). Chrome in Windows seems to handle everything fine but for some reason it won't work in Fedora. I get errors saying that my browser doesn't support 3d transforms.

Comment: and in ubuntu 12.04 not work correctly. please help

Comment: Does the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335211/does-chrome-12-really-support-css-3d-transforms-including-on-linux?rq=1) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome/ium is probably the most popular option, so if the version you tried wasn't working, you may want to update to the very latest -- something like the Chromium Daily Builds. If even that is too buggy to work with, you might want to try a different Webkit browser for Linux.

Midori and Epiphany are two decent options. As an added bonus, I think both of these browsers will use the version of Webkit that you have installed on your system (unlike Chrome, which comes with its own version of Webkit). That means that you should be able to build Webkit from the latest nightly source release, and Midori or Epiphany will automatically use that version.

[WebKit Nightly Builds](http://nightly.webkit.org/)

I hope that this help you.