# Detect if computer can support 3D Transforms properly

Tags: css, browser-detection, css-transforms, graceful-degradation

When I detect webkit, I add an additionnal stylesheet using 3D Transforms properties.
Although it is working fine on many different computers *(All on the same chrome version)*, some don't render the animation properly.
 Those are older computers with cheaper Graphic Card. *(I guess that is what is causing the problem.)*
Is there a better way to detect if a computer can handle Css 3D Transforms than rely on the browser detection?

Answer (score -1):

Use Modernizr and its csstransforms3d class name.

More on these links:

http://modernizr.com/

http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-css

Comment: This will help detect if the _browser_ supports css 3d transformation. I think the question is more about if there's a way to know if the computer will be able to render the css 3d tranforms properly.

Comment: **Downvote explication**: As @Pat mentionned, This will detect if the _browser_ supports css 3d transformation, not if the computer will. For example: An old computer with the lastest version of Chrome won't render properly css 3d transformation, even though Chrome theoretically does.

Comment: Yes this only detects support. Testing how well it supports i think is not possible as of now.